# How to get a unique mobile ID for Firefox OS

Tags: mobile, firefox-os, msisdn

I'm trying to get a unique mobile ID for each user who uses my firefox os application.

I was thinking about MSISDN but it seems to be illegal to do that, send MSISDN to anther server is illegal.

Is there anyway to get a unique mobile ID for firefox OS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Mobile Identity API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/MobileIdentity).

It is not illegal to get the user's phone number as long as the user agrees to share it. The Mobile Identity API takes care of asking the user before verifying and providing the MSISDN to the requesting app.

Comment: thanks again for your answer ! do you know which permission I should use to get the MAC address

Comment: @YasserB. what do you need the MAC address for? The API is only available for internal apps. as far as I know, check the WifiManager on mdn.